# How to use Windows ConPTY API from a process whose output has been redirected?

Tags: c++, winapi, pty

I am working on an application which creates a Windows pseudoconsole (using [the new ConPTY API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creating-a-pseudoconsole-session)).

It starts a PowerShell session (for test), and shows everything ConPTY sends from that session via the pseudoconsole, and everything works really well. Until I redirect the parent program output to anywhere.

Here's my full code listing for reference.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std::string_literals;

void throwLastError(int number)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Error "s + std::to_string(number) + ": "s + std::to_string(GetLastError()));
}

STARTUPINFOEXW prepareStartupInformation(HPCON hPCon)
{
    STARTUPINFOEXW startupInfo{sizeof(STARTUPINFOEXW)};
    SIZE_T bytesRequired = 0;
    if (InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(nullptr, 1, 0, &bytesRequired))
        throw std::runtime_error("InitializeProcThreadAttributeList wasn't expected to succeed at that time.");

    const auto threadAttributeList = static_cast<LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST>(calloc(bytesRequired, 1));
    startupInfo.lpAttributeList = threadAttributeList;
    
    if (!InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(threadAttributeList, 1, 0, &bytesRequired))
        throwLastError(4);

    if (!UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
            threadAttributeList,
            0,
            PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PSEUDOCONSOLE,
            hPCon,
            sizeof(HPCON),
            nullptr,
            nullptr)
    )
        throwLastError(5);

    return startupInfo;
}

PROCESS_INFORMATION startProcess(STARTUPINFOEXW startupInfo, const std::wstring &commandLine)
{
    std::vector<wchar_t> cmdLineBuffer;
    for (auto x : commandLine)
        cmdLineBuffer.push_back(x);
    cmdLineBuffer.push_back(L'\0');
    
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo{nullptr};
    if (!CreateProcessW(
        nullptr,
        cmdLineBuffer.data(),
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        FALSE,
        EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        &startupInfo.StartupInfo,
        &processInfo)
    )
        throwLastError(6);

    return processInfo;
}

int main()
{
    auto h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    auto type = GetFileType(h);
    std::cout << "STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE " << h << " " << type << std::endl;
    
    try
    {
        HANDLE inPipeRead = nullptr, inPipeWrite = nullptr;
        if (!CreatePipe(&inPipeRead, &inPipeWrite, nullptr, 0))
            throwLastError(1);
    
        HANDLE outPipeRead = nullptr, outPipeWrite = nullptr;
        if (!CreatePipe(&outPipeRead, &outPipeWrite, nullptr, 0))
            throwLastError(2);
    
        HPCON hPCon = nullptr;
        if (CreatePseudoConsole(COORD { 80, 25 }, inPipeRead, outPipeWrite, 0, &hPCon) != S_OK)
            throwLastError(3);

        CloseHandle(inPipeRead);
        CloseHandle(outPipeWrite);
    
        auto startupInfo = prepareStartupInformation(hPCon);

        auto processInfo = startProcess(startupInfo, L"powershell.exe");
    
        std::cout << "PID: " << processInfo.dwProcessId << "\nTID: " << processInfo.dwThreadId << "\n";

        char buffer[1024];
        DWORD readBytes = 0;
        while (ReadFile(
            outPipeRead,
            buffer,
            sizeof buffer - 1,
            &readBytes,
            nullptr
        ))
        {
            buffer[readBytes] = 0;
            std::cout << "Read bytes: " << readBytes << "\n";
            std::cout << buffer << "\n";
        }
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error &x)
    {
        std::cerr << x.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

So, if I start this program from terminal or from an IDE, it works (and tells how much data it has read from the PTY pipe). But if I start it with output redirected (e.g. `myprogram.exe > C:\Temp\somefile.txt`, or even `myprogram.exe | out-host` in pwsh), then it stops working: the PowerShell then somehow inherits the stdin and stdout and doesn't write anything to the PTY pipe.

For diagnostics, I've added output of `GetFileType(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE))`, which helps to detect if the output has been redirected (since it's not always obvious in practice). For pristine stdout, it should write `2`, and other numbers for other output modes.

How can I overcome this issue? Is it possible for my program to work even if its own stdout/stderr were redirected somewhere? I thought one of the points of PTY was to create a separate isolated environment, which won't interfere with the parent one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [got answered dy Dustin L. Howett on Microsoft Terminal issue tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/11276):

> A-ha! We did do some work to improve handle inheritance, but **only** if the inherited handles were console handles (so: the spawned application would connect to its *parent's* stdin/stdout even if it was supposed to be using a pseudoconsole)
>
> ```cpp
>     //
>     // If we are establishing a Pseudoterminal Connection, close
>     // any in/out/err handles that may have been copied from the parent.
>     // We will re-make new connections to the given PTY instead of
>     // using the automatically inherited handles.
>     //
>         
>     if ((ProcessParameters->ConsoleFlags & CONSOLE_USING_PTY_REFERENCE) != 0)
>     {
>         ConsoleCloseIfConsoleHandle(&ProcessParameters->StandardInput);
>         ConsoleCloseIfConsoleHandle(&ProcessParameters->StandardOutput);
>         ConsoleCloseIfConsoleHandle(&ProcessParameters->StandardError);
>     }
> ```
>
> We didn't do the same for all other inherited handles, so... I'm going to file a bug on the docs to make sure we document the need for `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES`.

So, for such cases, it's required to pass `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` in `startupInfo.StartupInfo.dwFlags`.